# PHPDoc for parameters and return type

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm using eclipse to build my php applications and the Source > Generate Element Comment function for automatically creating doc blocks.
I'm wondering a bit about the format because the return type is set as full-qualified class name but the parameters not.
Is this a bug of the IDE or is it the common convention?

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Executes the given service.
 *
 * @param string $serviceClass
 * @param ParametersInterface $inputParams
 *
 * @return \ZF\Hal\Entity
 */
```

And I have the following uses:

```
namespace MyApp;

use ZF\Hal\Entity;
use Zend\Stdlib\ParametersInterface;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely just a behavior oddity in Eclipse, where the auto-recognition code for parameters is possibly *not the same code* that auto-recognizes returns.  I would bet the parameter recognition is more naive, in that it probably keys specifically off your method signature.  So, if your method signature is

`public function executeService(string $serviceClass, ParametersInterface $inputParams)`

then the auto-doc probably gets exactly just the `ParametersInterface` you have in the code.

However, if you wrote the code this way

`public function executeService(string $serviceClass, Zend\Stdlib\ParametersInterface $inputParams)`

then I'd bet the auto-doc would show the fully namespaced name.

It wouldn't hurt to report it to Eclipse (if it's not already been reported).

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you have `use ParametersInterface;` with it's path on top of file, so PHP doc takes it into account, but you don't have `use ZF\Hal\Entity`, so it's inserted in @return with full path.
In PHPStorm it works like this, so probably in Eclipse it works the same

Comment: Yes, in PHPStorm you are also given the option to import the fully qualified path too, I'm not so savvy with eclipse but I would imagine it works the same way

Comment: I thought exactly like you: If I use a class, then it's not necessary to set the full path in param and also not in return. But that's exactly the fact which confused me: I used both classes. I modified my post.